# Internet Explorer css styles break after postback from referring php page

Tags: php, css, caching, post, internet-explorer-9

I thought I'd throw this out there just to see if anybody has experienced this issue and knows a likely cause/fix off the top of their heads.

I have a PHP page that loads a table of data (built in PHP) with an EDIT link that gets echoed out on each record.  The link takes you to an edit page with a user ID and record ID added as parameters to the URL in the edit page.  Once the edits are complete and the user submits the changes, they are taken back to the page that showed the data table of records.  Everything works successfully except that when they're returned back to the referring page, the DIVs are now all shoved over to the left instead of nicely centered as they were when the page was first loaded.  Also, it's evident that some of the other styles are lost in the return trip as well.  This ONLY happens in IE (using IE9), and not in FF or Chrome.

I've used Fiddler and the W3C validator to try and narrow down the problem, but my gut is telling me it's either an issue with how IE caches things, or it's a goofy PHP issue posting stuff back into the page before the styles are applied.

Any thoughts??

Thanks!

---

**SOLVED:**

Thanks to GolezTrol for the initial advice that led me in the right direction!

I took a closer look at the HTML and found the answer right at the top of the document.

The way this works is when PageA.php loaded, the HTML and styles loaded fine and the page had no errors. When you clicked an EDIT link in the data table, it took you to PageB.php where the info could be edited and submitted back to the database, at which point you were redirected back to PageA.php to see the updated table. When PageA.php loaded again, the page was wrecked and my DIVs were pushed over to the left border, and some styles were lost.

The error was occurring due to a javascript alert that posts when coming back from the referring PageB that lets you know the database was updated. The PHP script was injecting that alert into the document before the DOCTYPE declaration and the rest of the HTML, therefore blowing up my page. To fix it, I just replaced the initial alert with a true/false variable, and then placed the PHP injected alert inside the body of the document.  All is good now!

Firefox and Chrome handled the error, but IE9 is much harder on bad programmers. :-)

Thanks for all of the quick responses and advice!

Comment: What if you just look at the source and compare the before and after versions in a tool like WinMerge? That the HTML is valid doesn't mean it is good. Or the same, for that matter.

Comment: I'll try WinMerge (though I've already tried doing exactly that in Notepad++). I guess my question to you then is: Why would the page load correctly on first load, but then its styles get screwed when posting back from another page?

Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: i would just inspect element in Chrome. but winmerge sounds like you're doing the same thing. if you can post the url, be alot easier to help debug :)

Comment: If the output is only a little different, that may cause great differences in the layout of the page. Maybe a cookie, session information or whatever reason causes such a difference. I don't have your source, and not even the outputted HTML, so I can't be any more specific. But there must be a difference or else you wouldn't get different results. If you find the difference, small as it may be, you will probably quickly find its cause.

Comment: @GolezTrol ...Thanks, you led me to the right answer. See my edit above!

Comment: IE is much harder on good or bad programmers :)

Comment: @GregR.: Please add your solution as an answer below and accept it. This will mark your question as answer then which is how this site works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @hakre: Done! Sorry, I wasn't exactly sure how to handle that. I got the impression it wasn't kosher to use the "Answer your own question" option for some reason. (i.e. It might hurt my cred somehow). Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It does not hurt. The opposite is the case, others can vote it up. Additionally, this cleans up the "Unanswered Question" section. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to GolezTrol for the initial advice that led me in the right direction!

I took a closer look at the HTML and found the answer right at the top of the document.

The way this works is when PageA.php loaded, the HTML and styles loaded fine and the page had no errors. When you clicked an EDIT link in the data table, it took you to PageB.php where the info could be edited and submitted back to the database, at which point you were redirected back to PageA.php to see the updated table. When PageA.php loaded again, the page was wrecked and my DIVs were pushed over to the left border, and some styles were lost.

The error was occurring due to a javascript alert that posts when coming back from the referring PageB that lets you know the database was updated. The PHP script was injecting that alert into the document before the DOCTYPE declaration and the rest of the HTML, therefore blowing up my page. To fix it, I just replaced the initial alert with a true/false variable, and then placed the PHP injected alert inside the body of the document. All is good now!

Firefox and Chrome handled the error, but IE9 is much harder on bad programmers. :-)

Thanks for all of the quick responses and advice!